windowing bug on Ubuntu 24.04
Just today, I have upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.  I noticed that the windowing system for apps such as Minecraft, Discord, VSCode, and GitHub Desktop.  Started to have a window glitch. Apps like Steam, Thunderbird mail, and Firefox do not have this issue.
What I have Tried:

reinstalling apps
updating drivers
rebooting ubuntu

Minimized small windows
work well with a chance that that when mouse clicking, may switch to the window under it, but will quickly switch back
maximized Window
the whole Right half of screen has the same problem.
FullScreen
the Right Half completely switches to the window under it.
I also noticed that resizing windows is not really possible.

I found this GitHub issue under the VSCode repository which led me to decide to test it out with the apps I listed above.  Except I use X11 and not Waylands. So I believe this is an Ubuntu bug.

System info:

OS Name: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS,
OS Type: 64-bit
Gnome version: 46
Windowing system: X11


I'm still running 22.04.4 & considering running 24.04.  I also run X11 & I'm wondering how it is going for you running X11 on 24.04.  Now that you solved the mutter issue, is everything basically the same as when you were running 22.04 (or previous)?  Thanks

Turns out that from one of my other questions
input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4
that I still had the PPA mutter installed.  switching back to normal mutter was the solution.
